# How to set task on android that will run each midnight?

Tags: java, android

I need to set task on android that will check for new data and download it from the remote server.
Basically i know how to run task, but the question is:
Should i run the  scheduleAlarm() method from the main thred?
it means that each time the user opens the app this method is being called.
Would it create duplicated tasks?
What is the proper way to set this kind of task?

```
public void scheduleAlarm(){
    Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
    date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);

    // create the object
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    //set the alarm for particular time
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,date.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,  intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
}


public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

    ConnectivityManager cm = null;
    NetworkInfo netInfo = null;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // exec task download data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Use the PendingIntent to start a service which executes the network request.</strike>

```
PendingIntent.getService(...)
```

But make sure that it ether an IntentService or the actual network request in executes async.

EDIT: Sorry I misread the question. The last argument in the PendingIntent specifies what to do when the PendingIntent already exists. In the example you are telling that if such an PendingIntent already exists, then it should be updated. So you should be fine as long as the arguments for the PendingIntent stay the same since no new PendingIntent is created.

Comment: So basically, my code will just update it? and wont create a new task?

Comment: The PendingIntent stays the same. But you can cancel any existing alarm, that matches the PendingIntent, with AlarmManager.cancel(thePendingIntent) before setting a new one.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

according to documentation alarmManager.set will cancel your pending event and schedule new one, which mean onReceive will be called one per event.

If you want to manage task, just keep its intense in AlarmReciever

public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

```
ConnectivityManager cm = null;
NetworkInfo netInfo = null;
Task task;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
 // reschedule alarm

 // check if not null and not finished return or cancel old one and create new 'task'



}
```

}